# Can we use swift with objective-c in same class

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have been reading through Apple documentation and as I read it is possible to use Swift classes in existing Objective-c project.
My question is, Can I use Swift code with objective-c  code in the same class, in my existing Objective-c project?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, a class must be defined in Swift or in Objective-C not mixed language inside single class file, sorry .

As you may have already noticed a class in swift is generally made by a single file with `.swift` extension, while objective-C class is defined using two files `.h` and `.m` . So, a  `.h` or `.m` can't contain swift code, the compiler will gives you some errors ...

Answer (score 2):

If you mean Objective C and Swift in the same file, no, you can't.

What you can do is create a class in Objective C, and add extensions in a Swift file, or the opposite